# How to check nil for a property already forcefully downcasts

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have a simple problem but couldn't find a proper solution. I have a swift code that looks like this.

```
 let id  = dic["id"] as! String
```

I need to check if *dic["id"]* is nil. I can check for nil like this

```
if let safeId = dic["id"]{
   let id = safeId as! String
}
```

But the problem is I have a number of values to be unwrapped and doing the above step for every property seems impractical. I would like to have something like below but it doesn't work because the downcasting always returns a value so it is not optional hence cannot be unwrapped.

```
if let snap = child as! DataSnapshot,
            let dic = snap.value as! [String : Any],
            let firstName =  dic["first_name"] as! String,
            let lastName = dic["last_name"] as! String,
            let image = dic["user_image"] as! String,
            let id  = dic["id"] as! String{
                  /* My code */
             }
```

This method gives an error called **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'**
 I'm not an advanced developer, please help me to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all `!` with `?`, `if let` unwraps **optionals**

```
if let snap = child as? DataSnapshot,
   let dic = snap.value as? [String : Any],
   let firstName =  dic["first_name"] as? String,
   let lastName = dic["last_name"] as? String,
   let image = dic["user_image"] as? String,
   let id  = dic["id"] as? String{
          /* My code */
   }
```

Your *I can check for nil* example is bad practice, too. It's supposed to be

```
if let safeId = dic["id"] as? String {
   let id = safeId
}
```

Please read (the section [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) in) the [Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing optional casting here, if you are force casting there is no point in putting it inside an `if let` block.

```
if let snap = child as? DataSnapshot,
            let dic = snap.value as? [String : Any],
            let firstName =  dic["first_name"] as? String,
            let lastName = dic["last_name"] as? String,
            let image = dic["user_image"] as? String,
            let id  = dic["id"] as? String{
                  /* My code */
             }
```